# I am not able to access data as per POJO class

Tags: android, getter-setter, pojo

Hi I have following json response, I am not able to access data of 'edit' jsonobject, how to create pojo for that?

Example

```
{
    "result":"",
    "responseMessage":"",
    "edit":{
        "id":"156",
        "user_id":"5466",

    },
    "data":[
         {
            "dataid":"1",
            "dataname":"tt"
        },
        {
            "dataid":"2",
            "dataname":"tt"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to create pojo class for this response

Comment: Please post the code you have so far so we can best help you.

Comment: if you are having trouble creating pojo class by your own use this website [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Comment: @Sub6Resources just help me with pojo class, i have created one but can you tell how to access data of edit json object.

Comment: Always use _JsonValidator_ for checking that your json is valid or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) link to create POJO classes for your JSON in future. However your JSON is also not valid, it contains an extra **,** in your edit object.

```
"edit":{
    "id":"156",
    "user_id":"5466",<--This comma

}
```

Answer (score 1):

your Json is incorrect. There is an extra "**,**" inside **edit** object. Remove that and try accessing data of **edit**

Still if you are unable to access, I am attaching following POJO for you to use.

```
public class ExPojo
{
    private String responseMessage;

    private String result;

    private Data[] data;

    private Edit edit;

    public String getResponseMessage ()
    {
        return responseMessage;
    }

    public void setResponseMessage (String responseMessage)
    {
        this.responseMessage = responseMessage;
    }

    public String getResult ()
    {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult (String result)
    {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public Data[] getData ()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData (Data[] data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Edit getEdit ()
    {
        return edit;
    }

    public void setEdit (Edit edit)
    {
        this.edit = edit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [responseMessage = "+responseMessage+", result = "+result+", data = "+data+", edit = "+edit+"]";
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is generally bad to do other people's work instead of them. It makes people even more lazy. Please don't.

Comment: thanks for help +1. and I am getting price like 1.000000 and i want to display 1. how to do that

Comment: you can just cast that value to int like, (int) price